# Luigi 'No Instance(s) Available'

Tags: python, windows, command-line-interface, luigi

On my Windows VM i'm running some small jobs with Luigi. I'm wondering why at the beginning of every run I get a message saying "No Instance(s) Available". Every time I rerun the program, one more of these gets printed; so after 10 runs I have 10 "No Instance(s) Available" messages.

It doesn't seem to affect the modules I'm running, so I'm just asking out of curiosity: Why is Luigi/Command Prompt telling me this, and are there any ramifications?

EDIT: getpcmd is the source of the wmic command that produces the message. That trail is:

```
interface._run -> interface._schedule_and_run -> lock.acquire_for -> lock.get_info -> lock.getpcmd
```

I think the culprit may be `_WorkerScheduleFactory` but that's speculation

Comment: That's a common message from wmic.exe when a query has no results. So, having never used Luigi, I downloaded and searched through the source for the string "wmi". The source of the message is probably [`getpcmd`](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/2.3.3/luigi/lock.py#L30) in lock.py. It's using wmic to get the command line for a process with the given PID, but apparently there's no process with that PID.

Comment: @eryksun great find! So I wonder where this `getpcmd` function is getting called from inside luigi, I pulled it out and ran it solo and it doesn't loop since it's only looking for one ID. I'll dig around. Luigi must be retaining the process IDs in some capacity...it's getting obnoxious now. I'm up to 20 of these messages at the beginning of a run.

Comment: I have created a pull request in the luigi git repo to fix this.